# not able to run npm in vue project

Tags: vue.js, npm

Though I had @vue/cli-plugin-eslint package in my dependencies, Its showing @vue/cli-plugin-eslint not found

Terminal Error:
PS C:\Users\dell\Desktop\infinity\500appsInfinity> npm run serve

> 500apps@0.1.0 serve
> vue-cli-service serve

node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:959
throw err;
^

Error: Cannot find module '@vue/cli-plugin-eslint'
Require stack:

- C:\Users\dell\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules@vue\cli-service\lib\Service.js
- C:\Users\dell\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules@vue\cli-service\bin\vue-cli-service.js
  at Function.Module._resolveFilename (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:956:15)
  at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:804:27)
  at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1028:19)
  at require (node:internal/modules/cjs/helpers:102:18)
  at idToPlugin (C:\Users\dell\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules@vue\cli-service\lib\Service.js:172:14)
  at C:\Users\dell\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules@vue\cli-service\lib\Service.js:211:20
  at Array.map ()
  at Service.resolvePlugins (C:\Users\dell\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules@vue\cli-service\lib\Service.js:198:10)
  at new Service (C:\Users\dell\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules@vue\cli-service\lib\Service.js:35:25)
  at Object. (C:\Users\dell\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules@vue\cli-service\bin\vue-cli-service.js:15:17) {
  code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
  requireStack: [
  'C:\Users\dell\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\@vue\cli-service\lib\Service.js',
  'C:\Users\dell\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\@vue\cli-service\bin\vue-cli-service.js'
  ]
  }

Here are my dependencies:

```
"devDependencies": {
"@intlify/vue-i18n-loader": "^1.0.0",
"@vue/cli-plugin-babel": "~4.5.0",
"@vue/cli-plugin-eslint": "~4.5.0",
"@vue/cli-plugin-router": "~4.5.0",
"@vue/cli-service": "~4.5.0",
"babel-eslint": "^10.1.0",
"eslint": "^6.7.2",
"eslint-plugin-vue": "^6.2.2",
"node-sass": "^5.0.0",
"sass-loader": "^10.1.0",
"vue-cli-plugin-i18n": "^1.0.1",
"vue-template-compiler": "^2.6.14",
"webpack-cdn-plugin": "^3.3.1"
```

},

Comment: If an app can't find dependencies... install them. `npm install`. package.json doesn't contain them, it's ~1kb file.

Comment: npm is already installed

PS C:\Users\dell\Desktop\infinity\500appsInfinity> npm -v
8.18.0

& I also had dependency in package.json
still its showing dependency not found

Comment: NPM is installed, but you need to install the packages specified in your `package.json` now. Go to your project and run `npm install`.